# Does MySQL processes run in user or kernel modes?

Tags: mysql, kernel, system-calls, vfs

I try to count IOPS and I/O size with SystemTap script and use MySQL to be workload.

I found `mysqld` doesn't call systemcall but `mysqld` has read/write on VFS.

So, do MySQL processes run in user or kernel modes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, they run in userland, like most other processes on your system.

You can easily check this point by just using ps -eaf.

The kernel processes are the ones in brackets []. Anything else is a user process.

Note that with MySQL, there is a way to bypass the VFS if you use raw devices. On Linux, this is more or less deprecated. People prefer to use files in O_DIRECT mode instead.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL may be using memory-mapped file I/O for reading and writing, which requires no syscalls other than the initial mmap() call.